# How to make a batch script that finds a file .bat in c recursively?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im new to batch scripting and im trying to learn how I can make a script that can go recursively through the folders and if its founded give me the path, if not echo a simple message.
i was starting by here:

```batch
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir bucle.bat /s/b') do @echo %f  %~tf
pause
exit
```

but Im kinda stuck.

Comment: [`%%~tf`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ben/2007/03/09/path-manipulation-in-a-batch-file/) will give the "last modified" date/time of your file. In your post you say you only need the path. Do you also need the 'last modified' date/time attribute of your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `for` command to process the output of a `dir` command. Just to found the file, you don't need all this. Simplify

```
dir c:\bucle.bat /s /b
```

This searchs the file, when found shows it with full path and if not found echoes a error message.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir bucle.bat /s/b') do @echo %%f  %%~tf
pause
exit
```

to echo only the path:

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir bucle.bat /s/b') do @echo %%f
pause
exit
```

you can also use `where` command: http://ss64.com/nt/where.htm
and the `exit` command at the end isn't necessary...
P. S.: all your code is the same as this: `dir bucle.bat /s /b`

Answer (score 0):

`↑` denotes missing elements in the original code:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir bucle.bat /s/b') do @echo %%f  %%~tf
rem    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑                                        ↑↑   ↑↑
pause
```

- `"delims="` - to  properly treat paths with spaces,
- `%%f` - loop variable.

You could specify starting directory for recursive searching:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir C:\myfolder\bucle.bat /s/b') do @echo %%f  %%~tf
```

or even

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir C:\bucle.bat /s/b') do @echo %%f  %%~tf
```